# ui-grid angular js - cell stuck in edit mode

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am adding a custom editablecelltemplate when using the ui-grid. The problem is once a cell enters edit mode, it remains there. The celltemplate is not showing at all later on.

This is the Javascript I am using:

```
name: app.localize('IsHiddenName'),
field: 'isHidden',
type: 'boolean',
cellTemplate:
    '<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents text-center\">' +
    '  <i class="fa fa-check-circle font-green" ng-if="row.entity.isHidden"></i>' +
    '</div>',
editableCellTemplate:
    '<div style="margin:5px;">' +
    '<div class="md-checkbox-list">' +
    '<div class="md-checkbox">' +
       '<input type="checkbox" id="check2-{{row.entity.id}}" class="md-check" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">' +
       '<label for="check2-{{row.entity.id}}"><span class="inc"></span><span class="check"></span><span class="box"></span></label>' +
   '</div>' +
   '</div>'+
   '</div>',
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is from misunderstanding uigrid custom editable templates.

UI Grid is not finishing cell editing by itself. It is waiting for event
`uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT.`

This event is emitting by 2 ui-grid directives:

1. For input element: ui-grid-editor **(your case)**:
   `<input ui-grid-editor type="checkbox" id="check2-{{row.entity.id}}" ... >`
2. For select element: ui-grid-edit-dropdown:
   `<select ui-grid-edit-dropdown ... >`
3. For custom element: you must emit event by yourself:
   `scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT);`